# Ajax readystate 3 (Chrome / IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mxhr

I'm playing around with some `comet` and `mxhr` technologys. As it turns out, `Chrome (5)` does actually fire a `readystate 3`, but the `responseText` is always **empty** there.

Until today I though only `InternetExplorers` (<8) would show that behavior.

Am I wrong here?

Can somebody confirm that `Chrome` does not fully support `ajax readystate 3` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and reading in `webkits` developer forum, I finally can tell what is happening and how to prevent that in `chrome / webkit / safari`.

It's all about the connection type. To make `chrome` work "correctly" (responseText is NOT null) within `ready state 3`, we need a content-type which is not subject to sniffing. For instance a Content-type: text/xml works fine.

Another important thing on `webkit` is that it does not render pushed data until there are enough bytes transfered. "Official" that `treshhold` is about 256 bytes. So you have to at least send that as a padding.

Anyways on my testing I figured that you need to send a whole lot more before `Chrome(5)` fires a state3 ajax event the first time. Around 1kb.

Comment: genius!  i've been spending a while try to figure this out.  i don't know why chrome wouldn't work on text/html, but it works fine with text/plain.  go figure.